# Signifcato di "uomini sbardati"

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> È già stato tanto aver avuto la forza di scappare e non crollare come morto sotto i piedi di Costantino. Risalii sulla strada senza toccar terra, gridando e avventando in una maniera che quelle due ragazze non si sentirono d’aspettarmi e scapparono, scapparono anche le pecore, e perfino gli uccelli scappavano nel cielo. Agli uomini lontani e **sbardati** urlai due o tre volte che avevo trovato Costantino impiccato, e gli feci il segno delle mani intorno al collo, poi cascai seduto sulla strada e mi misi a vomitare che non la finivo piú, come se avessi il didietro in bocca.

La mia domanda è: cosa significa "sbardato" riferito agli uomini, come appare in questo brano? Ho consultato la voce "sbardare" di parecchi dizionari e ho visto che significa togliere i finimenti a un cavallo, ma non ho idea di cosa possa voler dire un "uomo sbardato".

Comment: Quindi alla fine l'uomo di Rocchetta aveva ragione ed era morto per davvero!?

Comment: @LinuxBlanket: Sì, aveva ragione: questo contadino, Costantino, si era impiccato.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il significato di sbardati nel contesto da te citato è sparsi.

Gli uomini erano lontani e sparsi, non raggruppati

Infatti in [dialetto piemontese](http://alessandrialisondria.altervista.org/dialet-lissandren-dizionario-alessandrino-italiano/) esiste:

> zbardlè (v. tr.). spargere.

che italianizzato diventa sbardare.

Mio nonno usava il termine sbardare in dialetto quando ad esempio doveva andare ad allargare o spargere il fieno nei campi per farlo seccare meglio.